# Solving ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'abc'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have a python3 project. Its root directory is "abc". I am working on a python file located at:

```
abc/simulation/examples/myprog.py
```

In "myprog.py", I have a line

```
from abc import ...
```

but running the python file produces an error message

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'abc'
```

How can I remove this error? Thank you.

Comment: First of all `abc` is a built-in module. Second as the error suggests you don't have an `abc` module. Did you mean `from abc.simulation.examples import ...`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Python has a standard package `abc`. Reusing names of standard functions/classes/modules/packages is never a good idea. Try to avoid it as much as possible.
2. Do you have `__init__.py` file in your package?

Comment: Please avoid asking questions and asking for clarification in answers. This is what comments are for